# nmap 5.21 and Python problems

Tags: php, python

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

```
root@bt:~# rpm -vhU http://nmap.org/dist/nmap-5.21-1.i386.rpm
Retrieving http://nmap.org/dist/nmap-5.21-1.i386.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
    /usr/bin/python is needed by nmap-5.21-1.i386
    python >= 2.4 is needed by nmap-5.21-1.i386
root@bt:~# python -V
Python 2.5.2
root@bt:~# which python
/usr/bin/python
root@bt:~#
```

Comment: Which linux do you use?

Comment: backtrack 4 ....

Comment: Backtrack 4 is debian based and I believe it includes nmap by default.

Answer (score 2):

I had almost the same, just without `/usr/bin/python is needed by nmap-5.21-1.i386`. I had an older version of Perl.

I solved it by:

```
rpm -ivh --nodeps ./nmap-5.21-1.i386.rpm
```

nmap works correctly.

Comment: good point - you could just update the package. If `-ivh` doesn't work run `-Uvh` to update. To see if it is installed at all you can run `rpm -qa | grep nmap`

Answer (score 1):

I would almost guarantee you have more than one python installed on BT. You can use `whereis` to confirm.

```
 root@bt:~# whereis python
 python: /usr/bin/python2.5 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python2.5-config /usr/bin/python2.4 /etc/python2.5 /etc/python /etc/python2.4 /usr/lib/python2.5 /usr/lib/python2.4 /usr/local/lib/python2.5 /usr/local/lib/python2.4 /usr/include/python2.5 /usr/include/python2.5_d /usr/include/python2.4 /usr/include/python2.4_d /usr/share/python /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
```

It could be pointing to another version also in `/usr/bin/`

Best bet: to test, you could delete/move older versions of python from the directory. Or you can [use this video to run an Update Everything](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CtVKU_-Nlg0&feature=related) script. That will cover your ground.

Comment: any follow up on this one? I'm still interested.

Answer (score -1):

I confirm that I have both Python2.7 and Python3.6 installed on RHEL 8 and probably that's what causes the error.

Trying to remove Python3.6 causes the system to cry that it is needed by gnome-shell and some other Python 3 libraries.

I guess the only way is to just install it without dependencies as mentioned by Gaff, it seems to function properly.

Comment: What exactly does this question have to do with RHEL 8?  The question was asked 8 and half years before RHEL 8 was released

Comment: It became relevant again, I guess.